# Parsing Json into a dynamic c# object with a dynamic key

Tags: c#, json, parsing, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to parse this Google calendar response I'm getting from their Rest API using c#, but I seem to keep getting stuck. [edited] Update, the @ symbol isn't preventing the drill down, I verified by replacing the `@` with `_at_`.  See the screenshot of the Quick watch:
[image]

I'm sure I'm accessing this incorrectly...

Here's the `jsonString` I'm trying to parse:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
 "timeMin": "2015-06-12T14:00:00.000Z",
 "timeMax": "2015-06-14T14:00:00.000Z",
 "calendars": {
  "joe@bobs.com": {
   "busy": [
    {
     "start": "2015-06-13T18:30:00Z",
     "end": "2015-06-13T19:30:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2015-06-13T20:30:00Z",
     "end": "2015-06-13T21:30:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2015-06-13T23:00:00Z",
     "end": "2015-06-14T00:00:00Z"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

I've tried using:

```
dynamic myObj = Json.Decode(jsonString);
```

and

```
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

but I can't figure out how to get into the `joe@bobs.com` key (which is dynamic based on what I send up) to cycle through all the busy times.

Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it via a string indexer:

```
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(myObj.calendars["joe@bobs.com"]);
```

Comment: That did it, I was able to access the properties using this access method: myObj["calendars"]["joe@bobs.com"]["busy"][0].start  Thanks!

Comment: Question, is there any way to dynamically get the email address?  I do know it, but in the future if I didn't know it - how would I access it?  Is there some sort of child property or something similar?

Comment: foreach (var item in myObj["calendars"]) Console.WriteLine(item.Name)

Comment: I believe that for dynamic objects, you can usually use them like properties instead of like indexes, if you want (where variable name restrictions don't apply). `myObj.calendars["joe@bobs.com"]`

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with a similar problem in the past, however mine was a matter of hyphen, i simply replaced hyphen with underscore. you could potentially do something similar however seeing that it's a e-mail address, it might be a better to modify the schema (regular-expression seeing that you receive json from a third party API) create a new key "mail" so that you can ensure that you keep the original email address intact.

But perhaps more importantly, as you query this API perhaps you already knew the email, if so you could simply do a regex replace:

```
        string json = '... {"joe@bobs.com":...}...';
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b");
        string jsonfixed = regex.Replace(json, "email");
```

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I tried replacing the @ symbol, but it didn't help solve my problem - see the quickwatch screenshot above.  Seems like its a nested Json in Json?